# Rendered font becomes default font in Mozilla-Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, fonts, mozilla

I am making a website in which i am using "Gotham" Font throughout. On a button click, i display a Modal ( Bootstrap Modal). But when the modal comes, the font of entire screen changes to the default font of Mozilla.

If i specify  Font-family as

```
font-family : "GothamBold","Verdana",Arial,sans-serif
```

then it fallbacks to Arial but never to GothamBold

This problem is only in Mozilla on Linux ( Ubuntu 12.04 ). On windows, it works perfect.
What could be the cause of this? I cant share all the code because it belong to my company.

Comment: How are we suposed to reproduce your issue if you do not publish your code? Share a jsfiddle or something and then we could help you. Or you can ask "your company".

Answer (score 0):

1. this will only work if the font is installed on-system or if you use css fonts
2. GothamBold is not a valid font family name, the correct font family is probably Gotham with the Bold weight or something like that. Windows will tend to use old naming conventions that antedates normalisation while Linux will always prefer the most recent naming metadata present in fonts

fc-query will display what font names fontconfig reads in a font file under Linux.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/fc-query.1.html

To understand what is a valid font family name and what naming conventions a font must follow to work in modern apps (browsers, office suites, etc) you can read the Microsoft WWS whitepaper
http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-02-24-90-36/WPF-Font-Selection-Model.pdf

It describes how WPF tries to salvage legacy font naming. What you should remember is that most other software stacks, will not salvage anything. If the font naming does not already follow the target form things will fail.

Comment: i have the font downloaded and linked to it under font-face